# How to center a text over many columns of array?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

I would like to get the text *System of Figure* centered in the array.

**How can I center the text over the many columns of arrays such as here with four columns?**

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
\hline \text{} & \text{System of Figure } &  &  &  & \\
\hline \text{sets} & \{1,2\}^{*} & \{1,3\} & \{1,2,33\} &  & \\
\text{cuts} & \{1\}^{*} & \{2,3\} & \{1,22\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,22,3\}
\\\hline \end{array}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simply use `\multicolumn{5}{c}{\text{System of Figure}}\\ `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
\hline \text{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\text{System of Figure }}  \\
\hline \text{sets} & \{1,2\}^{*} & \{1,3\} & \{1,2,33\} &  & \\
\text{cuts} & \{1\}^{*} & \{2,3\} & \{1,22\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,22,3\}
\\\hline \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]